# Using ymm registers as a "memory-like" storage location

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, avx

Consider the following loop in x86:

```
; on entry, rdi has the number of iterations
.top:
; some magic happens here to calculate a result in rax
mov [array + rdi * 8], rax ; store result in output array
dec rdi
jnz .top
```

It's straightforward: something calculates a result in `rax` (not shown) and then we store the result into an array, in reverse order as we index with `rdi`.

I would like to transform the above loop not make any writes to memory (we can assume the non-shown calculation doesn't write to memory).

As long as the loop count in `rdi` is limited, I could use the ample space (512 bytes) provided by the `ymm` regs to save the values instead, but it seems awkward to actually do this, since you can't "index" an arbitrary register.

One approach would be to always shuffle the entire "array" of `ymm` registers by one element and then insert the element in the newly freed up position.

Something like this:

```
vpermq  ymm3, ymm3, 10_01_00_11b ; left rotate ymm by qword
vpermq  ymm2, ymm2, 10_01_00_11b ; left rotate ymm by qword
vpermq  ymm1, ymm1, 10_01_00_11b ; left rotate ymm by qword
vpermq  ymm0, ymm0, 10_01_00_11b ; left rotate ymm by qword

vblenddd ymm3, ymm3, ymm2, 3     ; promote one qword of ymm2 to ymm3
vblenddd ymm2, ymm2, ymm1, 3     ; promote one qword of ymm1 to ymm2
vblenddd ymm1, ymm1, ymm0, 3     ; promote one qword of ymm0 to ymm1

pinsrq   xmm0, rax, 0  ; playing with mixed-VEX mode fire (see Peter's answer)
```

This shows only handling four of the 16 registers, so evidently to do all 16 it will be a lot of code (32 instructions).

Is there a better way?

Unpredictable branches are undesirable, but we can still consider solutions that use them.

Comment: Just curious at the motivation for this? I can't imagine that shuffling AVX registers would be any cheaper than an L1 hit.

Comment: No, it absolutely doens't make sense from a performance point of view. The motivation is that the code that generates the value in `rax` is actually a small micro-benchmark using `rdpmc` to read performance counters and for benchmarks that deal with memory reads and writes, it is very nice not to have any "extraneous" memory activity associated with saving the results. I'm using this for "one-shot" mode in [uarch-bench](https://github.com/travisdowns/uarch-bench). @Mysticial

Comment: Oh ic. That's neat.

Comment: `(0 | 0 << 2 | 1 << 4 | 2 << 6)`.  You can also write shuffle masks in NASM as `10_01_00_00b`, if you like `_MM_SHUFFLE` / Intel diagram order of highest element first.

Comment: `vpextrq rdx, ymm0, 3` [only looks at the low bit of the imm8](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXTRB:PEXTRD:PEXTRQ.html), i.e. it's the same as `vpextrq rdx, ymm0, 1` unfortunately (it's an AVX1 instruction, not AVX2).  You can't access the upper lane with insert/extract instructions.  To copy elements from one register to another, use `vpblendd`, like maybe `vpermq` into a tmp then `vpblendd`.

Comment: `vshufpd dst, s1, s2` has some limitations: it has to take the low qword of each lane from src1, and the high from src2 (but it can do a different shuffle in the high/low lanes).  **If you were using just the XMM registers, `vmovhlps` is a high-to-low insert.**

Comment: Self-modifying code is impossible without writing to memory, and you can't index registers.  Can you branch *predictably*, with a pattern the branch predictors can learn?  Otherwise yeah, I don't see anything better than a giant branchless brute-force stack without AVX512 masked `vpbroadcastq` and rotating mask registers.

Comment: The coreboot had a C compiler to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes - oops, good point about `vpextrq` not being able to reach the high lane. I tried a different approach now with `vblendd` instead to move the high word (which is the low word after a rotate) into position. It shaved an instruction and 2 uops per reg also, nice. Does it look right?

Comment: I haven't tried to follow an element through the rotations.  But `vpblendd` uses dword elements.  `imm8 = 3` would select the low qword, i.e. the low *2* elements.  The comment on the instruction should probably say "low", not "high", or the "old highest".  Anyway, 16 independent shuffles followed by 15 blends is not horrible.

Comment: @PeterCordes - updated the mask, thanks. Changed the comment, I wasn't sure how to write it: it is the old high element, yes. You mention AVX512, but does it give a better solution here? One that isn't linear in the total number of registers used?

Comment: AVX512 lets you "index" within a register using `vpbroadcastq zmm0{k1}, rax`.  But it's still linear in the number of registers, and probably just offloads half the work to `kshift` instructions or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Yes, I see. You could do the same pre-AVX512 by broadcasting the index to all qwords and then doing a `cmp` and `blendv` with the original register and another register with the value to write also broadcast to all words - it's clunkier though! I guess there are kind of two separate questions here: implementing the more restricted "memory" I describe above, where the access pattern is known and sequentially increasing by one, and implementing a more general "memory" where the index is arbitrary. The broadcast stuff are perhaps especially useful for the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't [`vpinsrq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PINSRB:PINSRD:PINSRQ.html) into a YMM register.  Only an xmm destination is available, so it unavoidably zeros the upper lane of the full YMM register.  It was introduced with AVX1 as the VEX version of the 128-bit instruction.  AVX2 and AVX512 did not upgrade it to YMM/ZMM destinations.  I'm guessing they didn't want to provide insert into high lanes, and it would have been odd to provide a YMM version that still only looked at the lowest bit of the imm8.

You're going to need a scratch register and then blend into a YMM with `vpblendd`.  **Or (on Skylake or AMD) use the legacy-SSE version to leave the upper bytes unchanged!**  On Skylake, writing an XMM reg with a legacy-SSE instruction has a false dependency on the full register.  You *want* this false dependency.  (I haven't tested this; it might trigger a merging uop of some sort).  But you don't want this on Haswell where it saves the upper halves of all the YMM regs, going into "state C".

The obvious solution is to leave yourself a scratch reg to use for `vmovq`+`vpblendd` (instead of `vpinsrq y,r,0`).  That's still 2 uops, but `vpblendd` doesn't need port 5 on Intel CPUs, in case that matters. (`movq` uses port 5).  If you're really hard up for space, the `mm0..7` MMX registers are available.

---

#### Reducing the cost

**With nested loops, we can split the work**.  With a small amount of unrolling of the inner loop, we can mostly remove that part of the cost.

For example, if we have an inner loop produce 4 results, we can use your brute-force stack approach on 2 or 4 registers in the inner loop, giving moderate overhead with no actual unrolling ("magic" payload appears only once).  3 or 4 uops, optionally with no loop-carried dep chain.

```
; on entry, rdi has the number of iterations
.outer:
    mov       r15d, 3
.inner:
; some magic happens here to calculate a result in rax

%if  AVOID_SHUFFLES
    vmovdqa   xmm3, xmm2
    vmovdqa   xmm2, xmm1
    vmovdqa   xmm1, xmm0
    vmovq     xmm0, rax
%else
    vpunpcklqdq  xmm2, xmm1, xmm2        ; { high=xmm2[0], low=xmm1[0] }
    vmovdqa   xmm1, xmm0
    vmovq     xmm0, rax
%endif

    dec   r15d
    jnz   .inner

    ;; Big block only runs once per 4 iters of the inner loop, and is only ~12 insns.
    vmovdqa  ymm15, ymm14
    vmovdqa  ymm13, ymm12
    ...
    
    ;; shuffle the new 4 elements into the lowest reg we read here (ymm3 or ymm4)

%if  AVOID_SHUFFLES       ; inputs are in low element of xmm0..3
    vpunpcklqdq  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0     ; don't write xmm0..2: longer false dep chain next iter.  Or break it.
    vpunpcklqdq  xmm4, xmm3, xmm2
    vinserti128  ymm4, ymm1, xmm4, 1  ; older values go in the top half
    vpxor        xmm1, xmm1, xmm1     ; shorten false-dep chains

%else                     ; inputs are in xmm2[1,0], xmm1[0], and xmm0[0]
    vpunpcklqdq  xmm3, xmm0, xmm1     ; [ 2nd-newest,  newest ]
    vinserti128  ymm3, ymm2, xmm3, 1
    vpxor        xmm2, xmm2,xmm2   ; break loop-carried dep chain for the next iter
    vpxor        xmm1, xmm1,xmm1   ; and this, which feeds into the loop-carried chain
%endif

    sub   rdi, 4
    ja   .outer
```

**Bonus: this only requires AVX1 (and is cheaper on AMD, keeping 256-bit vectors out of the inner loop)**.  We still get 12 x 4 qwords of storage instead of 16 x 4.  That was an arbitrary number anyway.

### Limited unrolling

We can unroll just the inner loop, like this:

```
.top:
    vmovdqa     ymm15, ymm14
    ...
    vmovdqa     ymm3, ymm2           ; 12x movdqa
    vinserti128 ymm2, ymm0, xmm1, 1

    magic
    vmovq       xmm0, rax
    magic
    vpinsrq     xmm0, rax, 1
    magic
    vmovq       xmm1, rax
    magic
    vpinsrq     xmm1, rax, 1

    sub         rdi, 4
    ja          .top
```

When we leave the loop, ymm15..2 *and* xmm1 and 0 full of valuable data.  If they were at the bottom, they'd run the same number of times but ymm2 would be a copy of xmm0 and 1.  A `jmp` to enter the loop without doing the `vmovdqa` stuff on the first iter is an option.

Per 4x `magic`, this costs us 6 uops for port 5 (movq + pinsrq), 12 `vmovdqa` (no execution unit), and 1x vinserti128 (port 5 again).  So that's 19 uops per 4 `magic`, or 4.75 uops.

You can interleave the `vmovdqa` + `vinsert` with the first `magic`, or just split it before / after the first `magic`.  You can't clobber xmm0 until after the `vinserti128`, but if you have a spare integer reg you can delay the `vmovq`.

### More nesting

Another loop nesting level, **or another unrolling**, would greatly reduce the amount of `vmovdqa` instructions.  Just getting the data shuffled into YMM regs at all has a minimum cost, though.  [Loading an xmm from GP regs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779309/loading-an-xmm-from-gp-regs).

**AVX512 can give us cheaper int->xmm.  (And it would allow writing to all 4 elements of a YMM)**.  But I don't see it avoiding the need to unroll or nest loops to avoid touching all the registers every time.

---

PS:

My first idea for the shuffle accumulator was shuffling elements one to the left.  But then I realized this ended up with 5 elements of state, not 4, because we had high and low in two regs, plus the newly-written xmm0.  (And could have used vpalignr.)

Leaving here as an example of what you can do with `vshufpd`: move low to high in one register, and merge in the high from another as the new low.

```
    vshufpd   xmm2, xmm1,xmm2, 01b     ; xmm2[1]=xmm2[0], xmm2[0]=xmm1[1].  i.e. [ low(xmm2), high(xmm1) ]
    vshufpd   xmm1, xmm0,xmm1, 01b
    vmovq     xmm0, rax
```

---

### AVX512: indexing vectors as memory

For the general case of writing to vector regs as memory, we can `vpbroadcastq zmm0{k1}, rax` and repeat for other `zmm` registers with a different `k1` mask.   Broadcasts with merge-masking (where the mask has a single bit set) give us an indexed store into vector registers, but we need one instruction for every possible destination register.

**Creating the mask**:

```
xor      edx, edx
bts      rdx, rcx          #  rdx = 1<<(rcx&63)
kmovq     k1, rdx
kshiftrq  k2, k1, 8
kshiftrq  k3, k1, 16
...
```

To *read* from a ZMM register:

```
vpcompressq zmm0{k1}{z}, zmm1    ; zero-masking: zeros whole reg if no bits set
vpcompressq zmm0{k2},    zmm2    ; merge-masking
... repeat as many times as you have possible source regs

vmovq       rax, zmm0
```

(See the docs for [`vpcompressq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPCOMPRESSQ.html): with zero-masking it zeros all elements above the one it writes)

To hide vpcompressq latency, you can do multiple dep chains into multiple tmp vectors, then `vpor xmm0, xmm0, xmm1` at the end.  (One of the vectors will be all zero, the other will have the selected element.)

On SKX it has 3c latency and 2c throughput, [according to this instatx64 report](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeX_InstLatX64.txt).

Answer (score 1):

A few options you could consider:

#### Unroll

If you unroll your loop (which necessarily has a limited number of iterations since the storage available in `ymm` registers is limited to 64 qwords) you would have the chance to use hard-coded logic to insert your result from `rax` directly in the right place, e.g,. with `pinrsq` or `movq` sometimes combined with a shuffle to let you access the high lanes. It will probably take only 1.25 instructions per iteration, much better than 32!

#### Vertical Lanes

Your current shuffling solution could be characterized as horizontal rotation through a register, carrying from the high qword of `ymm N` into the low qword of `ymm N+1`. That is, adjacent elements within one register are logically adjacent in your scheme. Instead, you could do a vertical rotation, where instead elements in a given `qword` lane are logically adjacent to the elements in the same lane in registers `ymm N-1` and `ymm N+1`. This avoids the need for any horizontal shuffling, and most of the shifting needs only a single register-register `mov`. You only need special handling for the first and last registers to wrap your elements around into the next lane.

Something like this:

```
; shift all lanes "up"
vmovdqa ymm15, ymm3
vmovdqa  ymm3, ymm2
vmovdqa  ymm2, ymm1
vmovdqa  ymm1, ymm0

; wrap from the top register back to ymm0, shifting to the left by 1
vpermq   ymm0, ymm15, 10_01_00_11b
; store new element
vpinsrq  ymm0, rax, 0
```

That's about as simple as you are going to get for a general "shift every element" strategy: a single `vmovdqa` per used `ymm` register, plus to additional instructions to do the wraparound and new element insertion. As far as vector operations go register-register moves are pretty much faster than any other type of operation since they can be move-eliminated (0 latency) and can execute 4 per cycle.

This approach does need a temporary register (`ymm15` in the example above) and I can't think of an easy way to eliminate that, so you'd be able to use at most 15 registers as part of your "queue".

#### Indirect Jump

You could do a calculated indirect jump based on the iteration count to a short (2-4 instructions) sequence that puts the element into the right place. Basically a `vpinsrq` and in some cases some additional shuffling to access the high lane.

This type of table could be fully general, i.e., allow writes to arbitrary indexes in any order, but if you knew you were indexing sequentially as above, you could simplify the table using that assumption (i.e,. you can handle the high lane by writing into the low elements first and then using a `vinserti128` or something like that to move them both into the high lane at the right time.

This table will presumably mispredict the first time though. After that, it may or may not, depending on the pattern and the strength of the indirect branch predictor.