# 896-bit integer? Or 16384-bit?

Tags: x86-64, bigint, extended-precision

Since has x86_64 has 14 general-purpose registers (`rsp` and `rbp` are for stack), could you make a 896 bit integer?

Or could you even use all 32 `zmm` registers (512-bit) to make a 16384-bit integer, by moving parts of it into the 64-bit registers and then calculating? I don't care if gmp is faster for this question.

Comment: You could use all available memory to create one long integer...

Comment: You can load registers with arbitrary values and say that each represents some bits of an abstract integer, but I don't see how this is meaningful or useful in any way.

Comment: Yes, obviously yes, you could do that; adc/sbb make those operations easy.  And you can use RBP for whatever you want.  You can even use RSP for anything you want, in user-space with no signal handlers.  You could *also* use the MMX state, in addition to the ZMM, k0..k7, *and* general-purpose integer state, all at once for a single integer.

Comment: Note that getting data between GP and high parts of ZMM regs will mean shuffling to the bottom for a read, or a masked broadcast to write.  (or store/reload to mem).  [Using ymm registers as a "memory-like" storage location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50915381) shows how.  I close this as a duplicate because other than "yes", it's not clear what kind of answer this question is looking for other than how to get data in/out of wide vector regs.  You know how to use add/adc, right?